# Changing default behavior of "Goto anything" in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When I press `CTRL + P`, I'd like to avoid the suggested files of a specific folder (doc/ in my case).
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: A Google search returned this [forum post](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7340). Is that what you're looking for or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I've answered this above in the comments, but I am providing an answer here so that it's no longer marked as unanswered.*

There is a similar topic on the [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7340) that discusses this.

In short you will need to add the following to your user settings (`Preferences -> Settings - User`) with any other directories or file types that you wish to ignore.

```js
// folder_exclude_patterns and file_exclude_patterns control which files
// are listed in folders on the side bar. These can also be set on a per-
// project basis.
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db"],
// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

Comment: The downside with this solution is that the folder disappear too from the sidebar :(

Comment: Hopefully it will get addressed in ST3. You could always prepend your searches with whatever folder your files are in, e.g. `src/filename` but that may get annoying over time.